# Validation with exclusion helper and localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, localization

- Ruby 2.3.0
- Rails 4.2.6

My application has different languages and I'm doing a validation of username attribute with 'exclusion' helper.

So far, so good. But I have many terms to prohibit that my model is getting very ugly.

```
#user.rb

validates :username, exclusion: { in: :reserved_words }

def reserved_words
    %w(word1 word2 palavra1 palavra2 ...)
end
```

Is there a way to add these reserved words inside a yml with locale?

Any thoughts about how to proceed or a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UsersHelper` for that.

**UsersHelper**

```
module UsersHelper

  class << self
    def reserved_words
       %w(word1 word2 palavra1 palavra2 ...)
    end
  end

end
```

**User.rb**

```
#user.rb

validates :username, exclusion: { in: :UsersHelper.reserved_words }
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you, but how could I use localization?